# QLocale to std locale

Tags: qt, c++11

Qt framework gives me locale as `const QLocale &locale` in `displayText` function. But I need to provide this locale to text source as `std::locale`. How to do this? So far, I'm just taking the risk of making `std::locale` instance:

```
class STDLocaleSingleton {
    STDLocaleSingleton(){};
public:
    static const std::locale &Instance(){
        static std::locale loc("");
        return loc;
    }
};
```